# Html/CSS Fixed Picture size so it won't resize when browser is smaller

Tags: html, css, height, width, fixed

I created an email template with a banner at the top of a two column table. Everything is good except the top banner. When the email is sent out, the picture gets resized if the window is smaller than the banner itself.

How can I keep the picture from automatically resizing itself if the mail window is small?

This is my code for the banner:

```
<img style="width: 710px; height:191px;" alt="" src="banner.png" height="191" width="710" />
```

The `src` has a whole URL that went there. I just shorten it to just the picture.

Comment: Have a read of the [Markdown help page](http://Stackoverflow.com/editing-help), it'll make things clearer for formatting code as code. =)

Answer (score 0):

If you set the size of the image in a CSS file, it should not change.

```
.image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Then apply this style to your image.

Comment: Is there any way to intergrate the CSS into the HTML since the software I'm using only gives options to edit the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

depending on the email client this may/may not work, it depends on whether the CSS directives are supported if it's webmail it most likely will be supported

Additionally make sure that the img tag's parent element has the proper width style.
if it's embeded in the the table as a colspan2 then make sure the table has the min-width set as well.